# Folder created in Photoshop not showing up in finder

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, adobe-photoshop

This is really crazy issue i'm experiencing here:

I downloaded the newest Photoshop CC 2015 and started working with it to crop some images for a client. After that, i've saved all the images for the web in a folder i created with the save-tool from photoshop.

Now when i navigate in the finder to that path the folder does not show up, but when i make ls in iTerm it shows me that the folder is there.

Strange, huh?

Whats wrong? Is the Photoshop version buggy? Even normal saving the .psd makes it disappear.

[image: finder]

[image: iTerm]

Answer (score 1):

`chflags nohidden path/to/the/file` will unhide your file in Finder.

Comment: not working.. also in the "all my files"-section the new saved files aren't showing

Comment: okay after reboot the folder is visible again.. strange things happen